# Os ativos de um produto cosmético são os componentes químicos?

Tags: significado-em-contexto

Os **ativos** de um produto cosmético são os componentes químicos?

Exemplo:

> RESHAPE LISS – Linha XY NewWay Professional. Máscara de remodelagem dos fios com alto poder de alisamento e hidratação. Seus **ativos** regeneradores e reconstrutores que agem sob o calor da prancha, promovem o controle do volume e a cauterização dos fios, deixando-os com uma beleza renovada.

Eu pesquisei e achei [este link](https://estilo.uol.com.br/beleza/noticias/redacao/2013/02/03/beleza-perigosa-saiba-identificar-ativos-potencialmente-toxicos-nos-cosmeticos.htm) por exemplo.

Eu pergunto porque, no início, pensei que podia significar "*qualidades*", e quero me assegurar.

Answer (score 4):

**Ativo**, neste caso, pode significar [**princípio ativo**](https://drauziovarella.com.br/genericos/o-que-e-um-principio-ativo/) (como já explicado [nesta outra resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4731/1798)). Seria a substância ou componente químico responsável pelos efeitos descritos - no caso, *"regeneradores e reconstrutores"*, ou seja, as substâncias que são responsáveis pela regeneração e reconstrução (dos cabelos, imagino).

Porém, como o termo **princípio ativo** é mais associado a [medicamentos](https://www.dicio.com.br/principio-ativo/) ou [alimentos](https://www.portaleducacao.com.br/conteudo/artigos/medicina-alternativa/principios-ativos-dos-alimentos-funcionais/39167), acredito que a escolha por somente **ativo** seja para evitar esta associação - não trabalho com publicidade, mas percebo que o termo **ativo** (sem a palavra "*princípio*") é mais utilizado em cosméticos, talvez para não associar com remédios ou comida (*mas esta minha "tese" pode estar errada, justamente por eu não trabalhar na área*).

No caso, acho que também é uma forma de apresentar qualidades do produto, aproveitando os [sinônimos de "ativo"](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ativo): *"que age ou atua/funciona"*, *"intenso/forte"* ou *"dinâmico"*. Ou seja, **ativos regeneradores e reconstrutores** seriam "coisas" que regeneram e reconstroem, e o fazem de maneira "ativa" ("*intensa*", "*dinâmica*", "*que funcionam*", etc).

Comment: Aprecio a explicação que você adicionou. Obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

Nesse caso específico, a frase poderia ser escrita da seguinte forma:

> Seus **princípios** ativos regeneradores e reconstrutores que agem sob
>   o calor da prancha, promovem o controle do volume e a cauterização dos
>   fios, deixando-os com uma beleza renovada.

Segue abaixo, a definição de princípio ativo:

> Princípio ativo (AO 1945: princípio activo) é a substância que deverá
>   exercer efeito farmacológico. Um medicamento, alimento ou planta pode
>   ter diversas substâncias em sua composição, porém somente uma ou
>   algumas destas conseguirão ter ação no organismo. Ainda em relação aos
>   medicamentos, denomina-se fármaco o princípio ativo deste.

Fonte: [wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_ativo)

Comment: Obrigada! Foi muito útil sua resposta. Saudações.